# applicationContext.xml is being copied to /WEB-INF/classes from src/main/resources

Tags: java, spring

however tomcat is throwing the error :

```
 IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml];
```

Which suggests that tomcat expects the applicationContext.xml to be one directory above where it is copied to. It is being copied to the **/WEB-INF/*classes*** directory, not just the plain old **/WEB-INF**

I am using maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `web.xml` you can state where your `applicationContext.xml` is located. If it is in `/WEB-INF/classes` then you must state `/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml` (and not just `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`).

Try this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

To include more than one context files you can use the `import` function. To do so, write into your `applicationContext.xml` one line per file like this:

```
<import resource="myOtherSpringContext.xml"/>
```

Comment: whats the stadnard way ? I assumed maven would just be the convention, I have not altered anything, afaik.  I guess the second question is how can I make maven copy src/main/resources to /WEB-INF

Comment: @NimChimpsky I have added some detail. I'll look up if it is enough (I think I missed the listener). You do not want to copy src/main/resources to /WEB-INF. Because your spring config doesn't belong there. I'll suggest you place it into /WEB-INF/spring/

Comment: @NimChimpsky So, now its complete.

Comment: OK, now I am getting the same for spring-servlet.xml :-(, but thats because I should keep that file in the root /WEB-INF ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky You can include other context xml files within your applicationContext.xml with the syntax `<import resource="spring-servlet.xml"/>` The path is relative to the location of the applicationContext.xml

Comment: spring-servlet is not referenced by the applicationContext.xml, but by web.xml

Comment: @NimChimpsky In my usual environment I keep my application context files (7 in my current project) in `/WEB-INF/spring/` one of them contains an import statement for all the others. This one (and only that one) is referenced in web.xml. This way the spring structure is nice and tidy.

Answer (score 6):

If you have put it under src/main/resources, you should refer to the resource as `classpath:/applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following syntax in your web.xml ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html ):

```
<!-- list of the configuration files to load -->
<context-param>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It will load it from the classes/* directory.
BTW, if you want to copy the applicationContext.xml directly in your WEB-INF directory, move it in /src/main/webapp

BTW, here is the way recommanded by the spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#context-create

HIH

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Maven behaviour, and is what a lot of people use with no objection. Why do you prefer it in WEB-INF?

Anyway, if you want it there, you can just put it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Comment: lol, I don't really mind where it is. But I moved it from webapp/web-inf to src/main/resources, as it made more sense and is the convention, which consequentl borked my deploy.

Comment: Yes, `src/main/resources` is the usual place :)

Comment: OK, now I am getting the same for spring-servlet.xml :-(, but thats because I should keep that file in the root /WEB-INF ?

Comment: Well, I put all configuration files in `src/main/resources`. In this case, you can set correct location in web.xml: you must set `contextConfigLocation` param in `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

the standard way is to create new source dir `src/main/webapp`. All files from this dir will be places in the same folder as WEB-INF in resulting war. So, inside this new source dir you can create `WEB-INF` and place you `applicationcontext.xml` in it.

so you structure would look much like

```
+src
+---main
+---+---java
+---+---webapp
+---+------WEB-INF
```

check [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) documentation